# In geometric algebra, what is the grade of a k-vector in an n-dimensional space？

Tags: geometric-algebras

It's a stupid question, but I am not figure it out. In the book I read, a k-vector in an n-dimensional space is defined as a linear combination of this space k-blade. I'm curious what is the grade of the k- vector, is it also k?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, grade selection is a linear operation.

${\left\langle{{A + B}}\right\rangle}_{{k}} = {\left\langle{{A}}\right\rangle}_{{k}} + {\left\langle{{B}}\right\rangle}_{{k}}$

If the grade-k selection of a multivector equals that multivector, it has grade-k.

Example: $\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2$, and $\mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_4$ are both 2-blades.  Their sum $\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 + \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_4$ cannot be expressed as a product, so is a 2-vector, not a 2-blade, and

${\left\langle{{\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 + \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_4}}\right\rangle}_{{2}} = {\left\langle{{\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2}}\right\rangle}_{{2}} + {\left\langle{{\mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_4}}\right\rangle}_{{2}} = \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 + \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_4,$

This sum, a 2-vector, has grade-2, as it equals it's grade-2 selection.

The dimension $n$ of the underlying vector space is not relevant.

Comment: thanks!    I seem to have seen a sentence that roughly means "most of the conclusions about k-blade can be directly applied to k-vector." Does this conclusion exist or has it been proved?

Comment: That would have to be examined on a case by case basis.  For example, many k-blades are invertible (specifically, if it's factors are all invertible), but k-vectors (like the example above), may not be invertible.

Comment: thanks for your example!